# How can I access the setup.py directory in Conda to 'comment out' packages?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda, cheminformatics

I'm pretty new to python so sorry if this is a silly question.

I'm trying to follow the code found here: https://baratilab.github.io/AugLiChem/install_guide.html
to install the AugLiChem packages in my Conda environment (it's the MacOS ARM64 Architecture one)

However the final line says "Before installing the package, you must go into `setup.py` in the main directory and comment out `rdkit-pypi` and `tensorboard` from the `install_requires` list since they are already installed. Not commenting these packages out will result in an error during installation."

Whenever I type `setup.py` it errors saying: `setup.py is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Any advice on how to access the directory to comment out the packages would be really helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: it is a perfectly good question, but if you are new to python, then why start with something this complicated ?  what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

`setup.py` is not a command but a Python code file that you find in the repo that you downloaded. You can open it with any editor.